# How to bind opengl process to the specific gpu card？

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu, nvidia

I have a server with two nvidia gtx960 cards. I do not use cross fire technique. That is to say, the gpu device ID is 0 and 1. I want to bind my OpenGL program to device 1 only, but leave device 0 free for other applications. How can I do this in my c++ code? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nVidia specific opengl extension to do that, see

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/WGL_NV_gpu_affinity.txt

There is sample code at the end of the specification.